# User filters on query results

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am looking to setup some filters on a page that loops results from a query.

The route:

```
@app.route('/member', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def member():
    #show activities
    activities = Activity.query.filter_by(moderation = "0")
    return render_template("member.html", title='Explore', activities=
        activities.items)
```

The HTML (`member.html`):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
    <h1>Things to do on a rainy day</h1>
    <p>Here are some suggestions of what you can do on a rainy day.</p><br>
    <div class="indexactivities">
    {% for activity in activities %}
            {% include '_activity.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and `_activity.html`:

```
    <table class="activitytable">
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="activityrow">
                <div class="activitytitle"><a href="{{ url_for('activitypage', 
                    activityid=activity.id) }}">{{ activity.title }}</a> &ensp;
                </div> 
                <div class= "activitylocation"> {{ activity.location }}</div>
                <div class= "activitymore"><a href="{{ url_for('activitypage', 
                    activityid=activity.id) }}">More info</a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I have found these solutions so far but I am wondering if there is something neater I could implement:

- with [JavaScript](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/10/24/using-python-flask-and-javascript-for-client-side-filtering-through-returned-data/) - I don't know any JavaScript
- via a [search form](https://dzone.com/articles/flask-101-how-to-add-a-search-form)
- via [global search](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-full-text-search)

Comment: You can pass filter_query in query_params of urls. And then you can filter result based on the varible you passed in query_params.

Comment: I think that's what I ended up doing (see below).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
@app.route('/member', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def member():
    form = Filter()
    # filters
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        location=form.activitylocation.data
        activities = Activity.query.filter_by(moderation = "0").filter_by(
            location=location).order_by(Activity.timestamp.desc())   
        
        # return redirect('filter', activities=activities)
        return render_template('member.html', activities=activities, 
            form = form,location=location)

    #show activities
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    activities = Activity.query.filter_by(moderation = "0").order_by(
        Activity.timestamp.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=
        app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'], error_out=False)
    next_url = url_for('member', page=activities.next_num) \
        if activities.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('member', page=activities.prev_num) \
        if activities.has_prev else None


    return render_template("member.html", title='Explore', activities=
        activities.items, next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url, form=form)
```

Probably not the most elegant way, but it works.

Comment: Alternatively, You can pass into ajax request to filter or can post req based filtering.